# I cannot get the Double click event to select all text in a ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have searched and tried many functions but nothing specific to my scenario works.

So, does anyone know why when I double click text in a combobox in VB.net it won't select ALL of the text?

So, I have a ComboBox that users can add text to (it acts like a search box but needs to be a ComboBox to show their history).

DropDown style is DropDown

I have a picturebox that I added the selectall to and it works but when I double click on any text it will not select all in the combo box.

Code:

```
Private Sub PictureBox2_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.DoubleClick
    MainSearchBox.SelectAll()
End Sub

Private Sub MainSearchBox_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MainSearchBox.MouseDoubleClick
    MainSearchBox.SelectAll()
End Sub
```

Comment: The default behavior of a ComboBox is that you can double click and select all the text. So what else have you done to it? Can you provide any code associated with it in the designer?

Comment: Have you checked whether the event is actually raised? -- The Control you click is not the ComboBox, it's the child Edit Control that presents the text, so its *Select All* feature is activated pressing `CTRL+A` -- The ComboBox Control *intercepts* all double clicks and *converts* them in a MouseDown event -- You could use a NativeWindow to handle the Edit Control's messages and, when it's `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`, call `SendMessage(Handle, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1)` (which means *select all the text*)

Comment: For example, see [Change color of the border of a ComboBox DropDown List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68058376/7444103). That code uses a NativeWindow to handle the messages of the ListControl of a ComboBox. You can do the same with the Edit Control, just change the return value of the `GetComboBoxListInternal()` method (also its name, probably), i.e., return `cbInfo.hwndEdit` instead of `cbInfo.hwndList`. Then, as mentioned, handle `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = &H203` (`EM_SETSEL = &HB1`)

Comment: I created a brand new project. Put a single combobox (style = DropDown).
Added text in the combobox g=how to find waypoints
When I doubleclick on any of the text, it only selects the single word. 
I need it to select ALL of the text in the combobox when double clicking any of the text

The code I used was this:
`Private Sub ComboBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DoubleClick
        ComboBox1.SelectAll()
    End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works.

```
 Private Property CBoxClick As Integer
    Get
        Return _cBoxClick
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _cBoxClick = value
        If _cBoxClick = 1 Then
            Dim thread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ResetClick)
            thread.Start()
        End If
    End Set
End Property
Private _cBoxClick As Integer
Private Sub ResetClick()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500) ' Adjust the duration as needed (in milliseconds)
    CBoxClick = 0
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.MouseDown
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        CBoxClick += 1

        If CBoxClick = 2 Then
            ' Double-click behavior here
            ComboBox1.SelectAll()
            ' Reset the click count
            CBoxClick = 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)