# Is there a way to remove blue border / Focus Rectangle from item list of Combobox DropDownList? .Net WinForms c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have custom made ComboBox that appearing like on this picture (with blue focus border)

[image]

Code:

```
using CxFlatUI;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App.Controls
{
    class CxFlatComboBoxEnhanced : ComboBox
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "White")]
        public override Color BackColor
        {
            get => base.BackColor;
            set
            {
                base.BackColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
        public override Color ForeColor
        {
            get => base.ForeColor;
            set
            {
                base.ForeColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
        public Color DropArrowColor { get; set; }
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "White")]
        public Color DropColor { get; set; }
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Gray")]
        public Color DropHoverColor { get; set; }

        public CxFlatComboBoxEnhanced()
        {
            DrawItem += CxFlatComboBoxEnhanced_DrawItem;
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            DoubleBuffered = true;
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            ItemHeight = 30;
        }
        
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == 0x000F || m.Msg == 0x133)
            {
                IntPtr hDC = GetWindowDC(m.HWnd);
                if (hDC.ToInt32() == 0) return;

                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(hDC);

                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.Clear(Parent.BackColor);

                GraphicsPath backPath = DrawHelper.CreateRoundRect(1, 1, Width - 2, Height - 2, 2);
                graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(BackColor), backPath);
                graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(BackColor, 2), backPath);

                graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), new Point(8, 8));
                if (DroppedDown)
                {
                    graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(DropArrowColor, 1), Width - 22, Height / 2 + 2, Width - 17, 15);
                    graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(DropArrowColor, 1), Width - 12, Height / 2 + 2, Width - 17, 15);
                }
                else
                {
                    graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(DropArrowColor, 1), Width - 22, Height / 2 - 3, Width - 17, 20);
                    graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(DropArrowColor, 1), Width - 12, Height / 2 - 3, Width - 17, 20);
                }
                graphics.Dispose();
                ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, hDC);
            }
            if (m.Msg == 0x0134)
            {
                IntPtr hDC = GetWindowDC(m.LParam);
                if (hDC.ToInt32() == 0) return;

                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(hDC);

                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.Clear(Parent.BackColor);
                
                graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(DropColor), graphics.ClipBounds);


                graphics.Dispose();
                ReleaseDC(m.LParam, hDC);

            }
        }

        private void CxFlatComboBoxEnhanced_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Index < 0) return;
            e.DrawBackground();
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            
            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(DropHoverColor), e.Bounds);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(base.GetItemText(base.Items[e.Index]), Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X + 8, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width - 8, e.Bounds.Height - 5), StringAlign.BottomLeft);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(DropColor), e.Bounds);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(base.GetItemText(base.Items[e.Index]), Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X + 8, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width - 8, e.Bounds.Height - 5), StringAlign.BottomLeft);
            }
            e.Graphics.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to remove this focus blue border. I have kinda working code that makes DropDownList appear like this

[image]

The part of the code responsible for this:

```
if (m.Msg == 0x0134)
            {
                IntPtr hDC = GetWindowDC(m.LParam);
                if (hDC.ToInt32() == 0) return;

                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(hDC);

                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.Clear(Parent.BackColor);
                
                graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(DropColor), graphics.ClipBounds);


                graphics.Dispose();
                ReleaseDC(m.LParam, hDC);

            }
```

But it removes border only when any item of list is in focus also painting Rectangle over the rest items also when I open list it appears with border and when I move my mouse outside of Form border appears too.
Is there a way to make it work properly using .net winforms c#?

Comment: [Change color of the border of a ComboBox DropDown List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68058376/7444103)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jimi's answer, I was able to solve the problem by slightly expanding his code:

```
using CxFlatUI;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App.Controls
{
    class CxFlatComboBoxEnhanced : ComboBox
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hWnd, ref COMBOBOXINFO pcbi);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal partial struct COMBOBOXINFO
        {
            public int cbSize;
            public Rectangle rcItem;
            public Rectangle rcButton;
            public int buttonState;
            public IntPtr hwndCombo;
            public IntPtr hwndEdit;
            public IntPtr hwndList;
            public void Init() => cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(this);
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "White")]
        public override Color BackColor
        {
            get => base.BackColor;
            set
            {
                base.BackColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
        public override Color ForeColor
        {
            get => base.ForeColor;
            set
            {
                base.ForeColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
        public Color DropArrowColor { get; set; }
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "White")]
        public Color DropColor { get; set; }
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Gray")]
        public Color DropHoverColor { get; set; }


        public partial class ListNativeWindow : NativeWindow
        {
            public ListNativeWindow() : this(IntPtr.Zero) { }
            public ListNativeWindow(IntPtr hWnd){ if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero) AssignHandle(hWnd); }
            public Color BorderColor { get; set; } = Color.Transparent;

            protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                if (m.Msg == 0x85)
                {
                    IntPtr hDC = GetWindowDC(m.HWnd);
                    if (hDC.ToInt32() == 0) return;
                    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(hDC);

                    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(BorderColor, 2), 0, 0, graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Width - 1, graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Height - 1);
                    graphics.Dispose();
                    ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, hDC);
                    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                }
            }
        }
        private ListNativeWindow listControl = null;

        internal IntPtr GetComboBoxListInternal(IntPtr cboHandle)
        {
            var cbInfo = new COMBOBOXINFO();
            cbInfo.Init();
            GetComboBoxInfo(cboHandle, ref cbInfo);
            return cbInfo.hwndList;
        }

        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
            listControl = new ListNativeWindow(GetComboBoxListInternal(Handle))
            {
                BorderColor = DropColor
            };
        }

        protected override void OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)
        {
            listControl.ReleaseHandle();
            base.OnHandleDestroyed(e);
        }


        public CxFlatComboBoxEnhanced()
        {
            DrawItem += CxFlatComboBoxEnhanced_DrawItem;
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            DoubleBuffered = true;
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            ItemHeight = 30;
        }
        
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == 0x000F)
            {
                IntPtr hDC = GetWindowDC(m.HWnd);
                if (hDC.ToInt32() == 0) return;
                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(hDC);

                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.Clear(Parent.BackColor);

                GraphicsPath backPath = DrawHelper.CreateRoundRect(1, 1, Width - 2, Height - 2, 2);
                graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(BackColor), backPath);
                graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(BackColor, 2), backPath);

                graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), new Point(8, 8));
                if (DroppedDown)
                {
                    graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(DropArrowColor, 1), Width - 22, Height / 2 + 2, Width - 17, 15);
                    graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(DropArrowColor, 1), Width - 12, Height / 2 + 2, Width - 17, 15);
                }
                else
                {
                    graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(DropArrowColor, 1), Width - 22, Height / 2 - 3, Width - 17, 20);
                    graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(DropArrowColor, 1), Width - 12, Height / 2 - 3, Width - 17, 20);
                }
                graphics.Dispose();
                ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, hDC);
            }
        }

        private void CxFlatComboBoxEnhanced_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Index < 0) return;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            
            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(DropColor), e.Bounds);
                GraphicsPath backPath = DrawHelper.CreateRoundRect(e.Bounds.X + 2, e.Bounds.Y + 2, e.Bounds.Width - 4, e.Bounds.Height - 4, 4);
                e.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(DropHoverColor), backPath);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(base.GetItemText(base.Items[e.Index]), Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X + 8, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width - 8, e.Bounds.Height - 4), StringAlign.BottomLeft);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(DropColor), e.Bounds);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(base.GetItemText(base.Items[e.Index]), Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X + 8, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width - 8, e.Bounds.Height - 4), StringAlign.BottomLeft);
            }
            e.Graphics.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Now ComboBox List looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzvtU.png)